# How to not animate transformation?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, objective-c-blocks, cgaffinetransform

How can I not animate transformation during moving some frame? I have some block with animation:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            self.center = [ViewController fitPointToNet:self.center];
            [self.delegate repaint];
        }];
```

And repaint call paintInView method. This method draw some figure (e.g. line) and rotate them. I want to animation look like line move to destination point - now it move and rotate.

```
- (void)paintInView:(UIView*)view 
{
//some drawing code   
line.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
//some drawing code
}
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the repaint method from within the animation block - so any changes to animatable properties of any view will be animated.

You should call that method from the completion block of the animation instead - use the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion` method instead of the one you are using now.

This will perform the transform without animating, after the animation has completed.

Comment: It's not solving my problem, because I want animate "//some drawing code". E.g. paintInView draws vertical line (in real it draws more complicated figure) starting from (x, y) and transforms it to horizontal line. self.center = [ViewController fitPointToNet:self.center] command changes starting point from (x, y) to (x2, y2). So I want to animate move horizontal line starting from (x,y) to (x2,y2). If I put transform into completion i get animated move vertical line from (x,y) to (x2,y2) and - after move end - line transform to vertical instantly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you want to animate drawn paths and figures then you should look at CAShapeLayer. You don't draw within animation methods, as a rule.

Comment: Oh, great. I'm newbie so - I try this :)